# Design my website something centered (horizontally + vertically)

Tags: css, html

I would like to design my website like this one: http://www.dior.com/couture/be_fr/product/view/femme/accessoires/bracelets/cuff-me-dior/bracelet-cuff-me-dior-16-1403.html/catId/3878/#

What is important for me:

- Having general background in dark color
- Having the main body (center) in bright color
- Having the main logo just above left of the main body
- Having the top menu just above the main body

In one word: something like on the link.

Does someone can point me in the right direction.

I don't know if this is important to know that I'll try to respect the HTML5 standard.

Thanks.

Comment: as much as we love to program, stackoverflow is not a free web shop. :S You should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting.

Comment: @Joseph: I don't ask the solution but that someone can point me in the right direction, like some 'standard' html/css template for achieve this, maybe a link that shows examples.

Comment: wonderful! Those kind of questions are fine and I see them on here all the time, but you do need to specify those specific questions in your posts and make sure to only post one question per post.  I'm sure there are several here who can point you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title of your question, you could vertically and horizontally center a div like this, provided you have a fixed width/height of the div (as per your reference) —

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

Which produces a result like this http://jsfiddle.net/YxYCT/

Comment: This is it, I was about to post this exact same solution

Comment: Thank you, you helped me much. I just have a problem aligning my menu on the bottom of the blue part. Can you take a look? Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YxYCT/3/